# Can I use the AWS-UpdateLinuxAmi AWS SSM Document to build AMI based on latest amazon linux 2?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ami, aws-ssm

I am currently evaluating, how to do automated AMI Baking in my AWS account.

I noticed the `AWS-UpdateLinuxAmi` AWS SSM Document, which seems like its kind of made for this task.

But it requires the AMIID as an Input parameter. I want to base my baked AMIs on the latest Amazon Linux 2 Image. Ideally without having to maintain my automation tasks.

Is this possible with Amazon SSM, or should I look for another solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SSM documents can automatically get parameters from **SSM Parameter Store**, as shown in the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/automation-variables.html):

```
LatestAmi:
    type: String
    default: >-
      {{ssm:/aws/service/ami-windows-latest/Windows_Server-2016-English-Full-Base}}
    description: The latest Windows Server 2016 AMI queried from the public parameter.
```

The example shows how to get **latest ami** for windows, but you can do the same for Amazon Linux 2. The SSM parameters for AL2 are listed and explained [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/query-for-the-latest-amazon-linux-ami-ids-using-aws-systems-manager-parameter-store/).